# How to make the email text body field as bold

Tags: email

I have set Email body in trigger as:

**mail.setPlainTextBody('Please find the attachment of Order Confirmation and Terms and Conditions documents for the Order -'+Orderid +'\n'+'\n'+'Sales Agent:  '+currentUser.name());**

I want the text

Please find the attachment of Order Confirmation and Terms and Conditions documents for the Order  as bold in email body output

**How to make the  text as bold in email body,what is the key for making bold as email body please anyone guide me for answer**

Comment: You can't make plain text bold. It's plain text. Why are you so committed to this strategy? Have you considered email templates?

Comment: then how i will make the plain text as bold @adrian larson

Comment: You cannot make plain text bold...it's plain text. It doesn't support formatting. I can't put it more plainly than that...

Comment: ok is there any other way to make the text as bold in the email body @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setPlainTextBody use [setHtmlBody(htmlBody)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) method, Using setHtmlBody method, we can use html code.

create a string

```
String strHtmlBody = 'Please find the attachment of Order Confirmation and ' + 
                     'Terms and Conditions documents for the Order -'+Orderid;
strHtmlBody = strHtmlBody + '<b>Sales Agent:</b>' + currentUser.name;
strHtmlBody = strHtmlBody + '<b>Sales Agent telephone number:</b>' + currentUser.Phone;
```

Now use this string in htmlBody

```
mail.setHtmlBody(strHtmlBody);
```

### Updates: Add `<br/>` tag

```
String strHtmlBody = 'Please find the attachment of Order Confirmation and ' + 
                      'Terms and Conditions documents for the Order -'+Orderid + '<br/>';
strHtmlBody = strHtmlBody + '<b>Sales Agent:</b>' + currentUser.name + '<br/>';
strHtmlBody = strHtmlBody + '<b>Sales Agent telephone number:</b>' + currentUser.Phone;
```

Comment: if it contains three elements, how to set body        mail.setPlainTextBody('Please find the attachment of Order Confirmation and Terms and Conditions documents for the Order -'+Orderid +'\n'+'\n'+'Sales Agent:  '+userinfo.getusername()+'\n'+'\n'+'Sales Agent telephone number:  '+currentUser.Phone); for this @ratan i want only sales agent and new lines should be there

Comment: @user36188 why you are using `\n` ? for new line ?

Comment: for new line how i will give in html body

Comment: how i will give new line in the html body

Comment: @user36188 check my updated answer. you follow the same steps that I followed to make bold  text

Comment: @user36188 use `<br/>` tag for next line in html

Comment: @user36188 your welcome

Comment: how to use <br> tag,i want  strHtmlBody = strHtmlBody + '<b>Sales Agent:</b>' + currentUser.name; i need br tag after this how? @ratan

Comment: three statemnts are seperated by new line how @ratan

Answer (score 0):

instead of `setplaninTextBody` use `setHtmlBody('<b>hi</b>')`

Comment: htmlbody with html text like `<b> text here</b>`

Comment: please share the answer how to make the email body text as bold @ratan for my input

Comment: @Ratan only salesagent part i want as bold text how

Comment: how to set html body in my trigger guide me @Ratan,@adrian larson

Comment: @user36188 check my answer